# How to Return a MatPlotLib Figure with its corresponding Legend

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to define a function which returns a pre-styled figure with certain grid, style, width and other properties. However, when I return the fig and its axes, the legend is missing. Here's a simplified example:

```
def getfig():
    plt.style.use('default')
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(1,1), sharey=False)

    if issubclass(type(axs),mpl.axes.SubplotBase):
        axs=[axs]

    for ax in axs:
        ax.grid(color='grey', axis='both', linestyle='-.', linewidth=0.4)
        ax.legend(loc=9, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.3), ncol=2)

    return fig,axs

fig,axs=getfig()
axs[0].plot(range(10), label="label")
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**:

This is what I'm using so far but I think there really should be a way to force *all* future legends associated to a figure to have a certain style.

```
def fig_new(rows=1,columns=1,figsize=(1,1)):
    plt.style.use('default')
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(rows,columns, figsize=figsize, sharey=False)

    if issubclass(type(axs),mpl.axes.SubplotBase):
        axs=[axs]

    for ax in axs:
        ax.grid(color='grey', axis='both', linestyle='-.', linewidth=0.4)

    return fig,axs

def fig_leg(fig):
    for ax  in fig.get_axes():
        ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.3), ncol=5)

fig,axs=fig_new()
axs[0].plot(range(10), label="label")
fig_leg(fig)
```

Comment: If you call `legend` before creating the artist that has a label to actually put into the legend, the legend will be empty and hence not be shown.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I see. I just called `legend` on `axs[0]` _after_ the call to `plot`; it worked. But this defeats the purpose. How am I supposed to define the position of the legend by default if I have to recall the `legend` after plotting? I'll try plotting nothing in the function.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, plotting an invisible dot in the function does not solve the problem.

Comment: sure, why would it? `legend` needs to come after the plot with the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the legend *after* an artist with a label is plotted to the axes.
An option is to let the function return the arguments to use for the legend afterwards.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

def getfig():
    plt.style.use('default')
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(1,1), sharey=False)

    if issubclass(type(axs),mpl.axes.SubplotBase):
        axs=np.array([axs])

    legendkw = []
    for ax in axs:
        ax.grid(color='grey', axis='both', linestyle='-.', linewidth=0.4)
        legendkw.append(dict(loc=9, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.3), ncol=2))

    return fig,axs,legendkw

fig,axs,kw=getfig()
axs[0].plot(range(10), label="label")
for i,ax in enumerate(axs.flat):
    ax.legend(**kw[i])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is very similar to what I've come up with. However, this solution is still partial, since a call still has to be made after plotting. I think there must be a way to define the way future legend-related artists are to be managed.

Comment: What makes you think that there must be a way to specify the position of a legend which is not yet created? Any hints on why you think that option should exist? Of course in principle anything is possible - so how deep are you willing to go into the code?

Comment: I would adventure that defining in advance the way all future legends should look is a pretty common use case. I mean, strictly speaking, the position of a legend which hasn't been created yet is no different than a fig which hasn't been created but upon creation shares the properties defined by a given template or in some properties array or file. I'm actually surprised by the fact this is not possible. At the moment I'm trying to return `axs` with an invisible plot and then replace the line with the actual plot, hoping the original legend properties persist.

Comment: You may customize how the legend looks using [rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html). But there is no way to preset the `bbox_to_anchor`. I would argue that without knowing the axes size etc. specifying the box is not useful. I could dig a little deeper if you want. But it would be good to know what other requirements you have. Is it always a single legend entry you want or could that number be dynamic as well?

Comment: Well, I guess it does not make sense to look deeper. It occured to me that whatever the solution, you will need to call some command after having plotted the artist. So that command may well be the one you already have in your code instead of a more complicated one.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to bother you with this. I'm finding my self producing many plots for different datasets. Therefore I wanted to create functions which automate the most cumbersome parts of plot generation. Perhaps I'll create a pull request some time.

Comment: The point is you need to call *something* to show the legend. So this *something* may be `ax.legend(**kw)` or it may be some other code, but because you need to call something anyways, this can be the legend command itself (or a wrapping function for it). Even if the bounding box could be specified as some default parameter beforehands, the only thing you gain would be to leave out the arguments: `ax.legend()`, instead of `ax.legend(**kw)`. A lot of work in order to save you 4 letters of typing.